# Communication between view and layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new on RoR and I'm trying to understand how the communication between the view and the layout works.

I found some [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#label-Communication+between+layout+and+template) and I get I need to use `provide` or `content_for` methods but it doesn't really explain how it gets accomplished.

Also, why do I need to use yield in my layout to print the value?

Example:
home.html.erb (view)

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
```

application.html.erb (layout)

```
<title>Great App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sub-view, you can use either of these methods by passing a block with text content (which can be useful for long content passages such as those that include HTML tags):

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  <h1>The Title</h1>
<% end %>
```

Or you can simply pass a string directly to `#content_view` as the second argument:

```
<% content_for :title, "The Title" %>
```

There's some better documentation for these methods in the [ContentHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) module.

Layouts just wrap other views, and subviews can be thought of as "blocks" that are passed to the layout. If you think of them that way, its natural that the `yield` keyword is used to invoke the subview like a block.

Comment: If he's providing content for a HTML title tag there's no need to add the h1 tag to it, `<% content_for :title, "The Title" %>` is enough.